# Matplotlib: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'float'

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to create a multi bar graph using matplotlib.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import _mssql
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://sa:california851101@127.0.0.1:1433/AffectV_Test')
connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute('SELECT pa.[Date],pa.[Type],(CAST((SUM(pa.Actions_Logged)/SUM(pi.Impressions_Served))*100 AS Decimal(4,4))) AS Daily_Action_Rate from Performance_Actions pa INNER JOIN Performance_Impressions pi ON pa.Alternative = pi.Alternative AND pa.[Date] = pi.[Date] GROUP BY [Type],pa.[Date] ORDER BY pa.[Date] ASC')

click = []
conversion = []
landing = []
xTickMarks = []

for row in result:
    if row[1] == 'click':
        click.append(str(row[2]))
    elif row[1] == 'conversion':
        conversion.append(str(row[2]))
    else:
        landing.append(str(row[2]))
    xTickMarks.append(str(row[0]))



connection.close()

ax = plt.subplot(111)
w = 0.3
ax.bar(xTickMarks-w, click,width=w,color='b',align='center')
ax.bar(xTickMarks, conversion,width=w,color='g',align='center')
ax.bar(xTickMarks+w, landing,width=w,color='r',align='center')
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.autoscale(tight=True)

plt.show()
```

I get the below error when i try and run the code:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-8a9e652a1846> in <module>()
     32 ax = plt.subplot(111)
     33 w = 0.3
     ---> 34 ax.bar(xTickMarks-w, click,width=w,color='b',align='center')
     35 ax.bar(xTickMarks, conversion,width=w,color='g',align='center')
     36 ax.bar(xTickMarks+w, landing,width=w,color='r',align='center')

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'float'
```

Tried converting the lists to numpy arrays, no go.

The result data set for the above code is:

```
01/04/2015  click       0.0036
01/04/2015  conversion  0.0010
01/04/2015  landing     0.0058
02/04/2015  click       0.0132
02/04/2015  conversion  0.0014
02/04/2015  landing     0.0104
```

Referring to the question [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270391/python-matplotlib-multiple-bars)

Comment: `xTickMarks` consists of `strings` ... so what do you intend to do by substracting a `float`?

Comment: I am not sure about that. I used the template given with the Matpotlib examples. Probably should check again.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `strings` in your `xTickMarks` I think you want to do this

```
ax.bar([float(x)-w for x in xTickMarks], ...)
```

In case that `xTickMarks` consists of floats you can also do

```
ax.bar([x-w for x in xTickMarks], ...)
```

or

```
xTickMarks = np.asarray(xTickMarks)
ax.bar(xTickMarks-w, ...)
```

Comment: Now I have the error `invalid literal for float(): 2015-04-01`

Comment: @TauseefHussain : Then you have the xticklabels in this list ... not the locations ... As far as I know `ax.bar` does not work like that. Have a look at [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html)

Comment: @TauseefHussain: I don't have much time now ... maybe I can propose a solution later.

Comment: Thank you for the help tough. I am working on it, will pitch it here if I find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

`xTickMarks` is a list.

`xTickMarks-w` raises the exception as you are trying to subtract a float (`w = 0.3`) from a list.

If you are trying to subtract `0.3` from every element of `xTickMarks`, then you should use plonsers approach.

Answer (score 0):

For
ax.bar(xTickMarks-w, click,width=w,color='b',align='center')
this to work.

You may try like this:

```
index = np.arrange(len(xTickMarks))
ax = plt.subplot(111)

plt.xticks(index, xTickMarks, fontsize = 9)


w = 0.3
ax.bar(index-w, click,width=w,color='b',align='center')
ax.bar(index, conversion,width=w,color='g',align='center')
ax.bar(index+w, landing,width=w,color='r',align='center')
```

This should work.