# Python , Create bar plot from dictionaries and put them side by side

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, graph

I am creating 2 bar plots from two different dictionaries. I would like to place my plots side by side. This how I make my plots from dictionaries:

```
w = 0.3

GD = {'A173': 63.992, 'A174': 13.368, 'A172':20.499, 'A171': 2.139}

plt.bar(range(len(GD)), GD.values(), align='center', color='green',width= w) 
plt.xticks(range(len(GD)), GD.keys())

BD = {'A173': 60.251, 'A174': 18.410, 'A172': 19.246, 'A171': 2.092}

plt.bar(range(len(BD)), BD.values(), color='red',width=w)
plt.xticks(range(len(BD)), BD.keys())

plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.xlabel(expl)
plt.title(att)
plt.show()
```

And this my output :[image]

How can I place my plots side by side ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270391/python-matplotlib-multiple-bars

Comment: @Dadep i am creating my plot from a dictionary , so it differs in some ways , plus  i am getting some errors trying to follow the question provided