# Plot multiple bars for categorical data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm looking for a way to plot multiple bars per value in matplotlib. For numerical data, this can be achieved be adding an offset to the X data, as described for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14270391/2969841):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.array([1,3,5])
Y = [1,2,3]
Z = [2,3,4]

plt.bar(X - 0.4, Y) # offset of -0.4
plt.bar(X + 0.4, Z) # offset of  0.4
plt.show()
```

[image: Multiple bars for numerical data]

`plt.bar()` (and `ax.bar()`) also handle categorical data automatically:

```
X = ['A','B','C']
Y = [1,2,3]

plt.bar(X, Y)
plt.show()
```

[image: Category handling]

Here, it is obviously not possible to add an offset, as the categories are not directly associated with a value on the axis. I can manually assign numerical values to the categories and set labels on the x axis with `plt.xticks()`:,

```
X = ['A','B','C']
Y = [1,2,3]
Z = [2,3,4]
_X = np.arange(len(X))

plt.bar(_X - 0.2, Y, 0.4)
plt.bar(_X + 0.2, Z, 0.4)
plt.xticks(_X, X) # set labels manually
plt.show()
```

[image: Manually setting category labels]

However, I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way that makes use of the automatic category handling of `bar()`, especially if the number of categories and bars per category is not known in before (this causes some fiddling with the bar widths to avoid overlaps).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is no automatic support of subcategories in matplotlib.

#### Placing bars with matplotlib

You may go the way of placing the bars numerically, like you propose yourself in the question. You can of course let the code manage the unknown number of subcategories.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = ['A','B','C']
Y = [1,2,3]
Z = [2,3,4]

def subcategorybar(X, vals, width=0.8):
    n = len(vals)
    _X = np.arange(len(X))
    for i in range(n):
        plt.bar(_X - width/2. + i/float(n)*width, vals[i], 
                width=width/float(n), align="edge")   
    plt.xticks(_X, X)
    
subcategorybar(X, [Y,Z,Y])

plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Using pandas

You may also use pandas plotting wrapper, which does the work of figuring out the number of subcategories. It will plot one group per column of a dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

X = ['A','B','C']
Y = [1,2,3]
Z = [2,3,4]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[Y,Z,Y], index=X)
df.plot.bar()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and code sample. I am aware of pandas capability to handle subcategories (in fact, my data is already stored in a dataframe), but for sake of consistency with other plots I was looking for a solution with matplotlib.

Comment: In order to rotate "A","B","C" on X axis, use df.plot.bar(rot=0)

Comment: the above answer, when using pandas, can also be simplified to  a one-liner: `df.set_index(X).plot.bar();` (this way, one doesn't lose the categorical names of the bars)

Comment: @Kevad Your comment is confusing, since `X` already ***is*** the index, so no need to set it again.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks for the correction. What I meant is that `df.plot.bar();` also produces the same output :)

Comment: @Kevad Yes, `df.plot.bar()` is what this answer proposes. Am I missing something? If not, we can probably delete all those comments?