# Multiple bar chart in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a dataframe like below one. There 4 cluster group and each group has several Venue options like Cafe or Coffee Shop. I want to make a bar chart mainly grouped by Cluster Labels with its Common Venues bars and it should show the Counts numbers.

I didn't manage it to plot in python. Could you help me?

```
Cluster Labels  1st Most Common Venue   Counts
    0                    Café               3
    0                    Clothing Store     2
    0                    Seafood Restaurant 1
    1                    Hotel              1
    2                    Café              14
    2                    Coffee Shop        1
    2                    Turkish Restaurant 1
    3                    Café               9
    3                    Restaurant         1
    3                    Steakhouse         2
    3                    Turkish Restaurant 3
    4                    Breakfast Spot     1
```

Comment: Please format your code and the dataframe.

Comment: I have just fixed it @Bazingaa Thx for your warning

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270391/python-matplotlib-multiple-bars

Comment: You can do like this it is already given i think

Comment: thank you @Shyam but it is not the one I was talking about. The example you send is I have found before but it jus groups the one main group parameter but I have two parameter in here. Each cluster group must has its own Common Venue