# Multiple barplot does not work for dataframe

Tags: python, plot, bar-chart

This is my data, i want to make a multiple barplot for the cluster that holds the columns so the bars would be 4 (represents panicattacks ,compulsivebehavior ,depression and anxiety)  and will repeat for each cluster (total is 6).

```
            panicattacks    compulsivebehavior   depression anxiety
cluster             
0                2.0               0.0                2.0   2.0
1                1.0               1.0                2.0   2.0
2                0.0               0.0                0.0   0.0
3                3.0               3.0                3.0   3.0
4                1.0               1.0                7.0   7.0
5                1.0               0.0                6.0   7.0
6                0.0               0.0                0.0   0.0
```

I want to make multiple barplot like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270391/python-matplotlib-multiple-bars). I followed and modified it but it does not work it shows, How should i do it?

```
ax = plt.subplot(111)
for i,row in enumerate(unemployed.values):
    ax.bar(unemployed.index[i], unemployed['panicattacks'], width=0.2, color='b', align='center')
    ax.bar(unemployed.index[i], unemployed['compulsivebehavior'], width=0.2, color='r', align='center')
    ax.bar(unemployed.index[i], unemployed['depression'], width=0.2, color='g', align='center')
    ax.bar(unemployed.index[i], unemployed['anxiety'], width=0.2, color='y', align='center')
```

[image: plot]

Comment: do something like this fig, [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4] = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=4)

Comment: attention this is a clue not the asnwer. your plt contains 1 ax and that's why it show 1 plot. In order to have more plots you need to define more ax

Comment: in each iteration assign to the correct ax

Comment: how should i iterate it? `for index,row in unemployed.iterrows():
    for col in unemployed.columns:` it doesn't work