# Is a grouped barchart by date possible in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

Suppose I have a need to create a visualization of the following format:

[image]

Wherein we have multiple categories, some belonging to the same class (ie. different types of successes, different types of failures).

Is there a way in matplotlib to create a rolling graph that can be updated with new dates as they come in?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python matplotlib multiple bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270391/python-matplotlib-multiple-bars)

Answer (score 0):

This is a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270391/python-matplotlib-multiple-bars).

TL;DR: No unfortunately it's not natively supported by matplotlib. You'll have to add multiple bar plots to the same axis, that is one for each category, and slightly changing the `x` values for each one so they appeare beside each other.