# How to plot two bar diagram for two colums of a given table using seaborn or matplotib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

This might be a simple task but I am new to plotting in python and is struggling to convert logic into code. I have 3 columns like below that consists of Countries, Quantities and Revenues:

| Country | Quantities | Revenues |
| --- | --- | --- |
| United Kingdom | 2915836 | 8125479.97 |
| EIRE | 87390 | 253026.10 |
| Netherlands | 127083 | 245279.99 |
| Germany | 72068 | 202050.01 |
| France | 68439 | 184024.28 |
| Australia | 52611 | 122974.01 |
| Spain | 18947 | 56444.29 |
| Switzerland | 18769 | 50671.57 |
| Belgium | 12068 | 34926.92 |
| Norway | 10965 | 32184.10 |
| Japan | 14207 | 31914.79 |
| Portugal | 10430 | 30247.57 |
| Sweden | 10720 | 24456.55 |

All I want to do is creating a side by side bars for each country which would represent the revenue and quantity for each region.

So far, i have came across performing this:

```
sns.catplot(kind = 'bar', data = dj, y = 'Quantities,Revenues', x = 'Country', hue = 'Details')
plt.show()
```

But this cannot interpret the input "Country".

I hope I am making sense.

Comment: Well the error should have been not interpreting "Quantities,Revenues" i believe. Anyway, what about `df.set_index("Country").plot.bar()`? or if you want separate y-axes for Quantities and Revenues, `df.set_index("Country").plot.bar(secondary_y="Revenues")`?

Comment: I set the Country as the index because that (whatever is in the index) is what goes to the x-axis values.

Comment: Noting that these use the embedded plotting functionality of pandas with the `.plot` accessor, which uses matplotlib under the hood.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, more granular control in vanilla matplotlib and styling are covered in answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14270391

Answer (score 2):

With [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), you can simply use [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) :

```
dj.plot.bar(x="Country", figsize=(10, 5))

#dj[dj["Country"].ne("United Kingdom")].plot.bar(x="Country", figsize=(10, 5)) #to exclude UK
```

With [seaborn](/questions/tagged/seaborn), you can use [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) after [`pandas.DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html)*ing* the original df.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)
dj_m = dj.melt(id_vars="Country", value_name="Values", var_name="Variables")
sns.barplot(data=dj_m, x='Country', y="Values", hue="Variables", ax=ax)
```

##### # Output :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` already has a built-in plotting function: `.plot` and you can choose which type by specifying it like; `.bar()`, `.scatter()` or using `kind=` and then the type; `kind='bar'` or `kind='scatter'`. So, in this situation you will use a bar.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # import this to show the plot

df.plot.bar(x="Country", **kwargs) # plot the bars

plt.show() # show it
```